# Intel 8080-based home computers

Tags: 8080, 8-bit-microcomputers

I'd like to build an FPGA replica of a home computer based on the Intel 8080. I am not looking to design my own computer, since I would like to tap into an existing software base.

Were there any Intel 8080 based home computers?

To clarify, I would like something that meets the following criteria:

- It is a general computing device, not a game console  / arcade machine (this rules out [Space Invaders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Invaders))
- A standalone machine (not a terminal like the [Compucolor 8001](https://oldcomputers.net/compucolor-8001.html))
- Keyboard and video output (unlike the [Altair 8800](https://oldcomputers.net/altair-8800.html))
- Boots to BASIC or comparably user-friendly setting
- Non-CPU parts documented well enough; even better if an open-source emulator exists

I know there is no shortage of Z80-based home computers, so there's always the plan B of just extending my i8080 into a full-blown Z80 and going from that, but if possible, I'd like to avoid that for now.

Comment: See https://code.google.com/archive/p/vector06cc/ for a working example of an FPGA replica of an Intel 8080-based Soviet home computer. Be sure to check out the project wiki that has important technical details. Software-based emulation does exist, not sure about it being open-source, though. Either way, I think it would be quite realistic to get in touch with the authors as they are active on a Russian forum https://zx-pk.ru/forums/55-vektor.html.

Comment: This is merely a point of interest, as the system does not meet your requirements: the NEC Spinwriter letter-quality printer used a full 8080 system on many large circuit boards as its control mechanism.

Comment: Go for Z80 - much more fun :)

Comment: [Pertec PCC2000](https://www.old-computers.com/museum/computer.asp?st=1&c=1300) was an 8085 based home computer, running CP/M. Unless you could find an actual machine, there would be issues, since most of the components (keyboard, video, hard drive) use interfaces, that probably aren't available today.

Answer (score 21):

The 8085, which came out two years after the 8080, rapidly became more popular for most applications because it required only +5 V power (as opposed to +5/-5/+12 V) and less external support circuitry. (Today there are a number of 8085 single-board computer designs available, such as [glitchworks](https://www.glitchwrks.com/2018/06/30/8085-sbc-rev3) and [OMEN](https://hackaday.com/2018/08/20/omen-alpha-a-diy-8085-based-computer/); 8080 designs [exist](http://www.s100computers.com/My%20System%20Pages/8080%20CPU%20Board/8080%20CPU%20Board.htm) but seem few and far between.) Because of this, I'd suggest you should consider an 8085-based design, rather than an 8080-based design.

The supply voltage differences are obviously of no importance to you given that you're rolling your own FPGA, but the other 8085 changes make a slight to large difference depending on just to what extent you're going to emulate the hardware.

At one extreme you could simply emulate everything in the FPGA, in which case you may still want to include a few extra software-visible features that the 8085 had over the 8080, such as the `SIM` and `RIM` (set and read interrupt mask) instructions and the additional interrupts, just in case you want to port 8085 software from other systems to yours. (This shouldn't affect backwards compatibility at all.)

If you start to bring specific buses/signals out of the FPGA so that you could interface external parts to it the way you could with a real 8080 or 8085, there are more differences you'd need to be congnizant of, such as the multiplexed address/data bus of the 8085. (Intel's chips designed for use with the 8085 had built-in support for this.) But in this case you'd also need to be concerned about the interfaces presented by the original computer system you're emulating.

Comment: I'm happy to move from 8080 to 8085 given how small the difference seems. But are there any 8085-based home computer designs that are not modern hobby projects but mass-market enough that there could be a reasonably-sized software library?

Comment: @Cactus While not as popular as the Z-80 even when you exclude mass-market home computers (such as the ZX80, MSX systems, etc.), there were a fair number of 8085 systems out there back in the late '70s and early '80s, mainly running CP/M. ISTR that most commercial CP/M software was 8080-compatible, and even [ZCPR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CP/M#ZCPR), the famed Z-80 Command Processor Replacement, could be built in an 8080-compatible version until version 3.3, so I don't think you'll find huge issues with software support for an 8085-based system.

Comment: That said, given that your focus is to find a (presumably commercial) "home computer" system rather than CP/M system, I don't think that the 8085 vs. 8080 distinction may make much difference for you. It's may well end up being just something to keep in mind should you a) want to port software from other systems, and/or b) interface 80s-era hardware with whatever you build.

Comment: @Cactus Most notably for the 8085 would be the quite well selling Kyotronic 85 series ([TRS-80 M100](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRS-80_Model_100), Olivetti M10, etc.). They are stand alone, have BASIC, lots of other software, simple (and all parts obvious). Only TV out is not standard but needs an extension. Still, doing an all in one Kyotronic would be a cool project I'd love to see or may even join.

Comment: The very popular handheld computer TRS-80 Model 100  used the CMOS version of the 8085. You can probably find a lot of documentation for it. But as others said here, the actual good source is the CP/M 2.x universe, as it's 8080 compatible by design.

Answer (score 15):

> Were there any Intel 8080 based home computers?

Yes, but the number is rather small, as at the point when the idea of a home computer as we know it today (and you describe) became popular, better 'versions' of the 8080 were already available, most notably the 8085 and Z80. Importantly for low cost computer design, they did away with -5 and +12V supply, thus simplifying power supply design a lot.

Some on this list may be

- [SOL 20](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sol-20) of 1976. As early as it can get for a desktop computer.
- [Compucolor II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compucolor_II) of 1977. A prototypical home computer due to its consequent consumer design.
- [Interact Home Computer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interact_Home_Computer) of 1978. Already quite late for an 8080 machine and mainly sold even later by liquidators. It might not fully fit your needs as the BASIC needs to be loaded from tape.
- [Micronique Interact](http://www.old-computers.com/museum/doc.asp?c=151) of 1980 (!). The same machine, but now made and sold by a French company.
- [DAI Personal Computer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DAI_Personal_Computer) of 1980. Originally designed to be the (European) TI home computer. Eventually the most ambitious machine of them all. Quite a great design for back then.

---

As said, the time of the 8080 for new designs was already long gone when home computers became a thing, so these are rather oddities - at least in the west. History is different within the former east bloc as their hardware/CPU development lagged behind (due to cloning), while information about microprocessor applications was ready available (as [Wilson already mentioned](/a/11683)).

There are 8080 clones like the Russian [КР580ВМ80А](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KR580VM80A) (1979) or the Polish [MCY7880](http://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/8080/Poland-MCY7880.html) (introduced rather late in the early 1980s). All of these machines were rather plain 8080 systems. Starting from Kits like [Micro-80](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micro-80) and [Радио-86РК](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio-86RK) all the way to quite modern, feature-rich systems like [Vector-06C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector-06C) and [Orion-128](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orion-128). The landscape was at least as diverse as in the West, if not more. All with a certain time shift.

More relevant to your task would be the rather large selection of software these machines featured, as each had (in their countries) a quite strong fellowship. On the down side, it's usually in the local language with no English documentation and hard to find, as relevant web pages are also in the same language - Google Translate is only a help **after** a relevant page is found.

Of all the Eastern 8080 based machines, the Czechoslovakian [Tesla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesla_(Czechoslovak_company)) [PMD 85](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PMD_85) is worth a look. Despite its name, it's not an 8085 CPU, but their own [MHB8080A](http://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/8080/Tesla-MHB8080A.html) (the semiconductor division is nowadays part of [ON Semiconductor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ON_Semiconductor)). The machine is not only remarkable for its huge amount of available software, but also for having evolved over the years from B&W to colour and into several spin-offs like the [MATO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MA%C5%A4O) - while the basic hardware is rather straightforward.

---

An oddity here was the otherwise usually advanced East Germany. While following the Intel lane (unlike [Bulgaria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pravetz_computers)), they skipped the 8080/8085 steps and went directly from i8008 ([U808](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_8008#Second_sources)) to Z80 ([U880](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U880)) - which is a story of its own. Thus even their earliest kits ([LC80](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/LC80)) and home/small computers ([Z9001](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robotron_KC_87)/[HC900](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KC_85)) used it from the start.

Then, why not use using some Hungarian machine? Sure, all (genuine Hungarian) machines I know of (Mikrokey Primo, Triton, Aircomp) are Z80-based, but it should be fairly simple to adjust the design to work with an 8080 - especially in FPGA, were the RAM is embedded anyway. After all, you should have much less hassle to dig up documentation and software for these, shouldn't you? :)) Of course, you may need some backward translator Z80 to 8080. So not much fun.

An only slightly different way would be switching the 8080 for an 8085, like [Curt sugested](/a/11686). In most respects, the 8085 is only a hardware update to simplify system build. Only two official new operations were included, which in addition almost never got used in full. Of course it had some lesser known but [quite handy extensions](/a/8041).

While I can't think of a plain 8085 home computer, the CPU is most notable for being used by the quite well selling Kyotronic 85 series - usually disguised as NEC 8201/8300, Olivetti M10, Tandy M100/M102. They are stand alone, have BASIC, lots of other software (in ROM and loadable), are simple (all parts obvious). Only TV out is not by default but needs an extension. Now, doing an all-in-one Kyotronic would be a cool project I'd love to see - or may even join.

---

### Conclusion:

> I'd like to build an FPGA replica of a home computer based on the Intel 8080.

- If you want to have *some* software to choose, you may settle for the Interact as the basic documentation is available in English (more advanced and most software in French) or any of the eastern (and learn Czech, Russian, ...)
- If you want hardware that allows to build your FPGA system in incremental but complete steps, the PMD 85 is your choice.
- If you want a well defined and satisfying system with lots of extraordinary features and few but awesome (system) software, go for the DAI (some French/Dutch might be helpful).
- If you want to have something with a **huge** user and software base, maybe even useful today, go for the Kyotronic 85 (no Japanese required) .

Comment: Heh din't know that there was i8080 based **Maťo**. I know only of [ZX clone named **Maťo**](http://www.8bity.cz/2015/dokumentace-ke-stavebnici-mikropocitace-mato/) which was Z80A based. But I did not pay much attention to i8080 computers back then other than PMD-85 and Didaktik Alfa/Beta. btw the PMD-85 was a year when they developed it (1985)

Comment: IIRC I saw it first time published in blue **AR** `Amatérske Radio` magazine as a How To with circuit and PCB. I think it was in one of these [1](https://www.bazar.sk/foto/amaterske-radio-1983-rocnik-xxxii-2/30100847/#foto-1) and [2](https://t1.aimg.sk/inzercie/ba_orig_3384877888_starozitnosti-a-zberatelstvo-zberatelstvo-amaterske-radio-1989-rocnik-xxxviii-2.jpg?t=LzB4NTc4L2ZpbHRlcnM6d2F0ZXJtYXJrKGluemVyY2llL2JhemFyLXdhdGVybWFyay1iaWcucG5nLC0xLC0xLDEpOnF1YWxpdHkoNzUp&h=rypwVhqsh1gqdCSm1tTmVw&e=2145916800) but I am not sure it could be even Red or Green **AR**. Looks like 2 is Mistrum not Maťo

Comment: Its not the Green AR ... I found the one I taught of and there are 2 different ZX clones not Maťo so its either in `[1]` or in some Red AR and too lazy to inspect which one (it was quite a lot of them over the decades) And the B&W scanned PDF archive of mine got 9GB !!! but sadly there are no front images so its really hard to search in it ... :( and no text search possible in it too :(

Comment: @Spektre (Caveat: I got no idea about Czech in particular) I've been told once that Matoa (sp?) has a meaning of 'Ghostly' in Czech, so it might have been popular choice for a computer, wouldn't it? (And BTW, I most definitely need these magazines).

Comment: LoL ... I believe you meant `Mátoha` that can be a ghost but it refer to some ugly slow monster like creature lurking in the dark (like mud-made elementals) but mostly it address the stage when you wake up in the morning before the first cup of tea or coffee and you are sluggish like a `Mátoha`... the name `Maťo` is just familiar version of `Martin`. In Czech word `Duch` is what you call `Ghost` in English.

Comment: @Spektre Now waitamomen, _"uggly slow monster"_ as well as _"sluggish"_ does fit a 2 MHz 8080, doesn't it? Even more so in 1989, when a Z80 outdated and home computers were 16 bit since years.

Comment: Heh :) fits exactly ... anyway 8bit was a thing a long after 1989 in eastern Europe...  I moved to x86 platform from Z80 only around 1995 ... as the 16 bits where too expensive and hard to get back then ... not to mention there where very few people using it ...  I think around 1993 the weights started to favor x86 platform in here (Former CzechoSlovakia ...)

Comment: btw I think this is a mirror of the AR archive I got on my drive [Amatérské Rádio (1952-2010  Acer)](http://www.diagram.com.ua/english/library/a-radio-prakticka-elektronika-magazine/a-radio-prakticka-elektronika-magazine.php?row=4) but i did not tried it (just the name matches) it should be around 9.8GByte of PDF's and programs (listings, hex and stuff). It was a collection of DVDs or CDs AR published years ago (I think to honor some aniversary)... Looks like the download is only 600MByte but its possible its OCR processed mine is not ...

Comment: there where 3 colors Blue where theme based but more oriented to construct some goal like receivers, computers, measurement devices etc, one goal per release) Red where practical electronics topics (all sorts of stuff in it from antenas to safety systems and the old ones got digital and MicroProcessor stuff topics in the middle part printed on green paper just between the adds it was mix of all stuff for everyone) the green ones where just one per year also theme based liek blue ones but much more in depth btw AR is still publishing I do not have the new ones but the old ones was better anyway

Comment: btw PMD-85 has also local well known funny acronym as "Pomalý Malý Debilný" which is in free translation "Slow Small and Stupid". The uComputer was fine but without periodic ~3 month maintanence  (removing all ICs from sockets and pushing them back) it earns its acronym pretty fast ...

Comment: @Spektre re: " ZX clone named Maťo " - no, it isn't. The link you gave is for the 8080 kit. ZX clones were the Didaktiks (Gama, Kompakt, M) and "homemade" Mistrum.

Comment: @RadovanGarabík Looks like my memory is playing tricks on me again I was sure it was ZX clone but you're right the circuit has MHB8080 in it. btw there where some more ZX clones In AR over the years.

Comment: The Sol-20 did not run on a Z80. It was an 8080. See the PDF of the Sol Systems Manual [here](https://www.sol20.org/manuals/sol_systems_manual.pdf).

Comment: @MTA You're of course right. I guess I screwed up while editing. No idea what I was thinking (and thanks, Igot the original manuals - together with the machine - siting at my workbench).

Comment: @Raffzahn the AR link I shared is valid but it contains only year 2010 Red, but scans are pretty good in comparison to mine with colors... The best ARs in my opinion where `1980-1996`  If you google a bit You should found it somewhere as complete set up to 2010 or even further mine archive is old...

Comment: @Raffzahn: we used to tell a joke back then: When the first 80386 gets to Czechoslovakia? When the US fires at us a Tomahawk missile.

Comment: @Edheldil LOL. Except I know better. They got there as soon as they were available in (Western) Germany. There have always been traditionally a lot of Czechoslovakians in Bavaria and most of them kept good contact with their relatives - this included shipping quite a lot of electronics across the iron curtain, which was suddenly anything but closed :)) I wish as many eastern computer would have made it to here ... not many in my collection.

Answer (score 12):

The Intel 8080 was apparently not that popular in the West for home computers. I think it was more marketed at industrial control or whatever, but I can't say for sure. Either way, Intel soon came up with its successors, the 8088 and so on, so the plain old 8080 wasn't that common.

But in the Soviet Union the KR580VM80A is basically the same thing as an 8080. It saw some use in some home computers (but was markedly less common than Z80 derivatives and PDP-11 derivatives).

The [Orion-128](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orion-128) and [Specialist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specialist_(computer)) are two examples of DIY computers that match your criteria, except that they boot to a monitor, not to BASIC.

The [Baltijets Juku](http://muuseum.at.mt.ut.ee/kogu/165.html) from Estonia I believe booted to BASIC, but I don't know that much is known about its internals.

The [Vector 06C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector-06C) from the Moldovan SSR is at any rate well-understood and boots to BASIC and has a library of software including homebrew games and has a lively community even today.

Comment: Wow, what a pleasant surprise to see Vector 06C mentioned on StackExchange! And, more surprisingly, it already has an FPGA replica: https://code.google.com/archive/p/vector06cc/

Comment: I would add Lviv PC-01(http://www.vcfed.org/forum/showthread.php?31665-Lviv-PC-01) as well as perhaps Irisha, Korvet and several others. Korvet in particular would be an interesting challenge to create an FPGA replica as it was one of the most powerful Soviet machines running on Intel 8080.

Comment: @DmytroL It seems you know more about that than me, I would be interested to read your answer here.

Comment: By the way, the Lviv PC-01 has a mixture of Russian and Ukrainian on the branding! From what I can tell it really says "Персональный компьютер Львів" on the front. What's up with that? Was that normal in Soviet Ukraine?

Comment: The Juku does boot into BASIC if ROMs are present. Otherwise (with the Bulgarian disk drive) it's a plain CP/M machine. At least mine is that way.

Comment: @Wilson Yes, this was normal. In the times of USSR (and Soviet Ukraine was a part of USSR till late Aug, 1991) Russian was the official language used for labeling because computers produced in Soviet Ukraine could be sold in Soviet Russia or any other part of the USSR. However, make/model names such as Львів could exist in a national language.

Comment: @Wilson later revisions of Vector 06C could boot into Basic thanks to the advanced bootloader that could boot into either software already stored in the bootloader ROM, or from an external ROM cartridge plugged into the parallel port (those were really rare as far as I can tell). But earlier revisions only had a quite bare-bones bootloader that only could load programs from a cassette tape.

Answer (score 11):

[PMD85](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PMD_85) was reasonably popular in Czechoslovakia, there is [a lot](http://www.schotek.cz/pmd/index.htm) [of documentation](https://pmd85.borik.net/) (if you can read Slovak or Czech), there are [several emulators](https://pmd85.borik.net/wiki/Emulator), including [an Open Source one](https://github.com/mborik/GPMD85Emulator).

Comment: Good point. Where was the CPU sourced? It was cloned/manufactured in CS or imported from GDR or USSR?

Comment: Also there was a very similar (but much less popular) computer called Maťo, basically forgotten today

Comment: @Wilson It used a local Czechoslovak clone ([MHB8080](https://www.cnews.cz/historie-ceskoslovenskych-mikropocitacu-prvni-krucky-v-dobe-totality/))

Comment: @Wilson (re: Maťo) there were also other clones, (unlike Maťo) quite compatible with the original PMD85 - Didaktik Alfa & Beta. Maťo has the dubious fame of being perhaps the last 8-bit computer aimed at low cost home market, while simultaneously not being compatible with anything ("almost compatible" does not count)

Comment: @RadovanGarabík +1 for the Didaktik Alfa/Beta everyone knows just Z80 based Gama these days

Comment: @Spektre ... which was *not* compatible with PMD85... (IMHO the most underrated forgotten machine was PP01 - though expensive as hell and not accessible for home users)

Comment: @RadovanGarabík completely forgot about that one ... have heard about it but never saw/use it ...

Answer (score 11):

I've found two computers that fit my bill of a "home computer" that use the Intel 8080 processor:

- The [Compucolor II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compucolor_II) from 1977 uses an SMC CRT5027 / TMS9927 video chip to produce color graphics. An open source emulator is [available on GitHub](https://github.com/jtbattle/ccemu). This one is very promising.
- The [Interact Model One](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interact_Home_Computer) from 1978 has a name that is very unsuited for googling, after all, which computer didn't have a Model One and what emulator isn't Interactive... I've found [this page in French](http://dchector.free.fr/) but the downloadable Zip only contains a Windows executable.

Comment: +2 for the Interact :)

Answer (score 9):

The [DAI Personal Computer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DAI_Personal_Computer) (Belgium, 1980) used an 8080A. It had some interesting features (optional maths coprocessor, servo-controlled [microcassette data storage](https://fjkraan.home.xs4all.nl/comp/dai/)) but was rather expensive.

Answer (score 5):

I think the 8080A based Triton meets your requirements (although it was a kit computer).

http://www.computinghistory.org.uk/det/6210/Transam-Triton/

I remember adding a S100 based 8K memory expansion out of 2114L chips.

I regret chucking it out when I moved home.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if these meet all of the criteria, but posting them since no one has .

[Polymorphic POLY 88](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphic_Systems_(computers)#Poly-88) - 8080 ? 8080A ? (  [Heres states it was a 8080A](http://www.old-computers.com/museum/computer.asp?st=1&c=563) )

[Micral G and Micral S](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micral#Later_models) - 8080

Answer (score 2):

The Canadian MIL MOD80 was either 8008 or 8080 depending* on which CPU card was used. A fellow in Canada has mad3 reproduction boards.

https://va3ngc.weebly.com/mil-mod-80-computer.html

Comment: Does it have video output?